# Avoid intersections of lines

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have timeline where should appear the appointments that are connected to it's origin date(see below). Problem in this issue is positioning the icon at the right place so that the connection lines don't cross.

So what I have so far:

[image: initial positioning]

In order to manipulate easily I have implemented the zones, the timeline is divided into zones and I place all the icons that has origin in this zone. Here is a problem of the lines that **crosses**.

[image: grid pattern]

The **ideal** solution would be this one, randomly spread the icons that lines does not cross:

[image: ideal]

I've thought of making "Pattern of Grid", defining the places where the icon could be placed and than have logic which one to connect to which dot.(max 12-15 dots in zones for example,they all could be on the same date as well) I've implemented my though on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7a80y74h/1/) before implementing in the project but it does not guaranty the result I want and is not **optimised** as well.

```
//See the demo on JSFiddle
```

So please, maybe you have some ideas how to reach my desired result(see above).

Answer (score 4):

If you just need the lines not to cross, you can put the icons wherever you want, make an initial assignment and then, as long as it's possible to swap a pair of icons so that the total length of those lines decreases, do that. The proof of correctness is pretty simple. Suppose we have a pair of crossing assignments

```
A   B
 \ /
  X
 / \
Y   Z
```

where `X` is the intersection point. Assuming that `AXY` or `BXZ` is a nondegenerate triangle, then it follows from the triangle inequality that

```
d(A, Y) + d(B, Z) < d(A, X) + d(X, Y) + d(B, X) + d(X, Z)
                  = d(A, X) + d(X, Z) + d(B, X) + d(X, Y)
                  = d(A, Z) + d(B, Y),
```

so we will reassign like so.

```
A   B
|   |
|   |
|   |
Y   Z
```

Convergence is guaranteed because the total length is always decreasing.

You may also want the lines not to be close together, in which case I would suggest that you investigate force-directed layout algorithms.

Comment: Thank you! I did not understand well how many comparisons do I need to prevent crossing lines. Let's take a simple exemple. If there is 5 icons(i[0]-i[4]) and 5 dots (d[0]-d[4]) what should be the pseudo code for this case? I mean complexity also.Does the swap between 2 icons(when lines are crossed) guaranties that other lines won't be affected and crossed by these lines?

Comment: @Natchkebiailia Look at TSP 2-opt for the inspiration here. The worst case running time is exponential in theory, but it's unheard of in practice -- usually a reasonable polynomial.

Comment: can you please please provide me a pseudo algorithm. let's take that we have already methods to check if 2 lines crosses and so on. I'm interested in loops, because I did not understand well your answer.

Comment: This answer would work also for this more specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38102768/47984.  Even better than iteratively swapping is to run maximum weighted bipartite matching to go straight to the optimal solution in poly-time.  (As you show, "crossing exists => sum of edge weights not minimal" -- thus "sum of edge weights minimal => no crossings".)

Answer (score 3):

To make sure the lines don't cross, connect the points on the timeline to the appointment icons as follows:

- Put the icons in a preliminary position (like a grid) at the top
- Go through the timeline points from left to right
- Calculate the direction from the point to each unconnected icon
- Connect the point to the icon in the left-most direction

The direction from the timeline point to the icon can be calculated in JavaScript using the `Math.atan2(dy,dx)` function, where dy is y<sub>icon</sub> - y<sub>point</sub> and dx is x<sub>icon</sub> - x<sub>point</sub>. The result is greater than π/2 for lines going to the left,  π/2 for vertical lines, and less than π/2; for lines going to the right.

[image: app lay-out example]

After this is done, you can move some of the icons down along their connecting line to create a more visually pleasing distribution. This can be done without the risk of creating crossed lines.

If you want to move an icon horizontally, check the direction of its neighbouring lines, to make sure you don't get too close to other lines.

UPDATE:

I think it may be beneficial to work from left to the middle and then from right to the middle, to get a more symmetrical distribution; otherwise points on the far right get connected to icons on the bottom row, which is not ideal.

You'll need to experiment with dragging the icons down along their connecting line. Starting with the bottom row and working your way up, you could decide how low to drag the icons based on how far the timeline point is from its neighbours, whether the neighbouring lines are convergent, how close to vertical the connecting line is, drag the icons in the center or on the sides first... You'll have to check to see which options give the best looking result.